# Extracting rows from an extremely large (48GB) CSV file based on condition

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, conditional-statements, extract

I have an extremely large CSV file which has more than 500 million rows.

But **I only need a few thousand rows from it based on a certain condition.** 
I am at the moment using:

```
with open('/home/Documents/1681.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['flag_central'] == 1]
```

Here the condition is that if the `flag_central == 1`, I need the row.

However, since the file is extremely huge, I am not able to perform the above code. I believe it is because of the `for` loop I am using, which is causing this trouble.

Is there anyway I can extract these certain rows from the CSV file based on the above condition?

Comment: use grep and filter what you want and pipe it into python and read it as csv.

Comment: @YOU: Can you please post an example as the answer?

Comment: What exactly is happening with the above code? Eating up memory? Infinite execution? Crashes with an error?

Comment: @deceze: Let's say infinite execution!! It's has been running for more than 1 hour now!!

Comment: it will take 500'000'000 / (time per row), so to get below 1 hour you'd have to process 500'000'000 / 3600 = 138'888 rows/seconds. Not sure that's easily achievable in a serial manner, with any approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-time task, I would suggest using unix commands first, then process the extract:

```
cat file | awk -F , '{ if ($5 == "1") print $0 }' > extract.csv
```

where -F specifies the column delimiter and 5 is the column number. figure this out first by

```
cat file | head -n 1 | tr ',' '\n' | nl | grep flag_central
=>
5   flag_central
^ this is the field number ($5)
```

This way you will not incur the cost of converting the csv file into python objects first. Depending on your use case YMMV.

Comment: How to perform the above for multiple commands? i.e. if I want to add another condition

Comment: the general form of the if statement is `if (expression) action`, where `expression` is any combination of operations that yield either true (non-zero) or false (zero). Thus you can combine multiple conditions using boolean operators, e.g. `if ($5 =="1" && $1 == "foo") ...`. For more complex examples please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=awk+conditions). Note if the conditional logic goes beyond a few terms, e.g. nested conditions or even parsing, I would recommend doing that as a second step in python instead of writing a complex awk script.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

chunk_list=[]
for chunk in pd.read_csv('/home/Documents/1681.csv', chunksize=10000):
    chunk_list.append(chunk[chunk['flag_central'] == 1]`

final_df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

Basically this will read 10000 rows at a time and filter the rows that don't meet your condition, these get appended to a list and when complete the chunks are concatenated into a final dataframe

Comment: I get the error, `TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: OK the `mode` is irrelevant really you can remove it

Comment: `final_df`, what sort of an array will it be?

Comment: it will be a pandas [dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). The only caveat I would have would be that with such a large file you would need to import the file in portions.

```
import pandas as pd
tp = pd.read_csv('/home/Documents/1681.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

From there you would then be able to extract the row you are interested in with:

```
rows = df[df['flag-central'] == 1]
```

If you would like to return this to a csv file you could then use to_csv:

```
rows.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a repetitive process and/or you have more complex conditions  to process, here is a fast, low-memory approach in Python that will get you there quickly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# put this in parsecsv.py, then chmod +x parsecsv.py
import sys
output = lambda l: sys.stdout.write(l)
for line in sys.stdin:
    fields = line.split(',')
    # add your conditions below
    # call output(line) to output
    if fields[0] == "foo":
         output(line)
```

This is intended to be used as a pipeline filter from the command line:

```
$ cat file | parsecsv > extract.csv
```

Actually I wrote a somewhat more [generic & maintainable template](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/ba998357daf3c255cf3ade2b0bc88497)  that you might find useful .